# C# Outer Apply in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, outer-join

How can I achieve Outer Apply in LINQ? I'm having a bit of a problem.

Here's the SQL Query I'm using.

```
SELECT u.masterID
      ,u.user
      ,h.created
FROM dbo.Users u
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM UserHistory h where h.masterID = u.masterID ORDER BY created DESC) h
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
from u in Users
join UserHistory on u.masterID equals h.masterID into h
select new {u.masterID, u.user, h.created.OrderByDescending().First()}
```

Answer (score 24):

```
from u in Users 
join UserHistory on u.masterID equals h.masterID into h 
select new {
  u.masterID,
  u.user,
  Created = h.Select(x => x.created).OrderByDescending(c => c).FirstOrDefault()
}
```

Or, with an association:

```
from u in Users
let created = u.UserHistories.Select(x => x.created).OrderByDescending(c => c).FirstOrDefault()
select new
{
  u.masterID,
  u.user,
  Created = created
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Outer Apply produces results of left outer join,
the query should be:

```
var q =
from u in db.Users
join h in db.UserHistory on u.masterID equals h.masterID into ps
from p in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { 
    masterID = u.masterID
    ,user = u.user
    ,created = ps.OrderByDescending(x=>x.created).FirstOrDefault()==null?null:ps.OrderByDescending(x=>x.created).First().created
};
```