# LINQ for "Outer Apply" / "Left Outer Join" kinda Query for PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql, linq, ef-core-6.0

I have a problem with my linq query, it performs really slow. And when I debug and see the translated query, I see what the problem is. My LinQ isn't really make the query I want.

Here's the LinQ I've got now:

```
from doc in context.document
from lasthistory in context.documenthistory
    .Where(x => x.documentid == doc.id)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.actiondatetime)
    .Take(1)
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
where lasthistory.actiondatetime >= periodFrom
    && lasthistory.actiondatetime < periodTo.AddDays(1)
select new
{
    id = doc.id,
    lastactionby = lasthistory.actionby,
    lastactiondatetime = lasthistory.actiondatetime
}
```

and here's the translated query from this linq

```
SELECT d.id, t0.actionby AS lastactionby, t0.actiondatetime AS lastactiondatetime
FROM dbo.document AS d
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT t.actionby, t.actiondatetime, t.documentid
    FROM (
        SELECT d0.actionby, d0.actiondatetime, d0.documentid, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY d0.documentid ORDER BY d0.actiondatetime DESC) AS row
        FROM dbo.documenthistory AS d0
    ) AS t
    WHERE t.row <= 1
) AS t0 ON d.id = t0.documentid
WHERE (t0.actiondatetime >= @__periodFrom_1) AND (t0.actiondatetime < @__AddDays_2)
```

It tries to select all data in documenthistory first, that's the reason my query performs really slow.

And I already update the LinQ now to be like this:

```
from doc in context.document
let lasthistory = context.documenthistory
    .Where(x => x.documentid == doc.id)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.actiondatetime)
    .FirstOrDefault()
where lasthistory.actiondatetime >= periodFrom
    && lasthistory.actiondatetime < periodTo.AddDays(1)
select new
{
    id = doc.id,
    lastactionby = lasthistory.actionby,
    lastactiondatetime = lasthistory.actiondatetime
}
```

It performs better than the first one, but the translated query kinda "ugly" with so many subqueries

```
SELECT d.id, 
    (
        SELECT d2.actionby 
        FROM dbo.documenthistory AS d2 
        WHERE d2.documentid = d.id 
        ORDER BY d2.actiondatetime DESC 
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS lastactionby, 
    (
        SELECT d3.actiondatetime 
        FROM dbo.documenthistory AS d3 
        WHERE d3.documentid = d.id 
        ORDER BY d3.actiondatetime DESC 
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS lastactiondatetime
FROM dbo.document AS d
WHERE ((SELECT d0.actiondatetime FROM dbo.documenthistory AS d0 WHERE d0.documentid = d.id ORDER BY d0.actiondatetime DESC LIMIT 1) >= @__periodFrom_1)
    AND ((SELECT d1.actiondatetime FROM dbo.documenthistory AS d1 WHERE d1.documentid = d.id ORDER BY d1.actiondatetime DESC LIMIT 1) < @__AddDays_2)
```

the query I want is like this:

```
SELECT d.id, t.actionby AS lastactionby, t.actiondatetime AS lastactiondatetime
FROM dbo.document AS d
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT d0.actionby, d0.actiondatetime
    FROM dbo.documenthistory AS d0
    WHERE d0.documentid = d.id
    ORDER BY d0.actiondatetime DESC
    FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
) t ON true
WHERE (t.actiondatetime >= @__periodFrom_1) AND (t.actiondatetime < @__AddDays_2)
```

Is there a way to do this in Linq? Or maybe Linq with result similar to this query?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: perhaps it was best to reconstruct the query from the ground up?

Comment: @BagusTesa so, what you mean is I should make the query first then translate it to linq later?

Comment: thats one way to do it. you can work with linq directly too. im not quite sure how to actually the query should look like given there is no sample data, expected output, and rules i must adhere to. for one, im clueless as of why the `where` part is not chained directly with `docunent_history` and the lack use of navigational properties.

Comment: this should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014362/c-sharp-outer-apply-in-linq

Comment: @BagusTesa I put the where condition for `period` is to filter the data for only certain last action period, so I need to do it outside of the `document_history`. I've already edit the question and put the query I want, I don't know how to do that query in Linq.

Comment: @Alander I already use that, but the result of the query looks really "ugly" as I mentioned in the question

Comment: @James it might be easier to build the query from the ground up provided we have proper [mcve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query). btw, aren't you [missing an `order by` in the join](https://dbfiddle.uk/ud9U3WTy)? also, i do curious whether [filtered `Include`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include) would do any favour. something like `context.Document.Include(d => d.DocumentHistory.Where(...).OrderByDesc(h => h.actiondatetime).First()).Select(...)`.

Comment: tbh, using ORM often times giving up some power of the query. they cant do many things which raw SQL can do. they provide convenience over performance.

Comment: @BagusTesa oh, I forgot to put the `order by` there, thank you. I'll take a look into the `Include` solution. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround which come to mind is to use `Distinct`. In this case, it is a little bit difficult to build `INNER JOIN` with Window function.
`DefaultIfEmpty()` removed, according to filter you need `CROSS APPLY`

```cs
var query =
    from doc in context.document
    from lasthistory in context.documenthistory
        .Where(x => x.documentid == doc.id)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.actiondatetime)
        .Take(1)
        .Select(x => new { x.actionby, x.actiondatetime })
        .Distinct()
    where lasthistory.actiondatetime >= periodFrom
        && lasthistory.actiondatetime < periodTo.AddDays(1)
    select new
    {
        id = doc.id,
        lastactionby = lasthistory.actionby,
        lastactiondatetime = lasthistory.actiondatetime
    };
```

From other side you can limit scanned range of records

```cs
var documents = context.document
    .Where(doc = context.documenthistory.Any(h => h.documentid == doc.id 
        && h.actiondatetime >= periodFrom
        && h.actiondatetime < periodTo.AddDays(1))
    );

var query =
    from doc in documents
    from lasthistory in context.documenthistory
        .Where(x => x.documentid == doc.id)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.actiondatetime)
        .Take(1)
    where lasthistory.actiondatetime >= periodFrom
        && lasthistory.actiondatetime < periodTo.AddDays(1)
    select new
    {
        id = doc.id,
        lastactionby = lasthistory.actionby,
        lastactiondatetime = lasthistory.actiondatetime
    };
```

Comment: Thanks! the linq with `.Distinct()` is the one I need, it performs much better than using `let`. also the query below the `.Distinct()` one, it will select all data in `documenthistory` first.